# Redirect Rule for hostname in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Let, `$staging_url = http://xx.xx.xx.xx/`

```
$mobile_url = http://xx.xx.xx.xx/mobile/xxx/testing
```

I have defined this redirect rule in my `htaccess` file:

```
 RewriteCond "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" "(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteRule "/(.*)$" "/mobile/xxx/testing/$1" [L]
```

When I hit **$staging_url** from my mobile, it redirects to **$mobile_url**. However, when I hit **$staging_url/design?id=23** . It again redirects to **$mobile_url** ,I want it to redirect to **$mobile_url/design?id=23**

Thanks in advance. I have used variables to define my link, as stack overflow allows only 2 links for users less than 10 reputation.
My .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks


RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule ^(.*)design$ story.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|ipad|iemobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/[0-9]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [mod_rewrite docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), you can take certain parts of the requested URL using parantheses and reference them later on, e.g.:

```
^/somepath(.*) /index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: The change is the question itself

Comment: I assume your IPs are the same in both cases? Just leave them out, it should work fine using relative paths!

Comment: Made the change, still doesn't works. What am I doing wrong here, I mean opening my site from browser, it's not even redirecting. Is ReWriteCond actually working?

Comment: try redirecting .* to google (or whatever) and see if anything happens. I've also noticed you stated that you have an `htaccess` file, it should be `.htaccess`, but maybe that's just a typo in the question? if it doesn't work, you can use phpinfo() to check if the mod_rewrite module is enabled.

Comment: I have added my .htaccess file. The file name  is .htaccess.  mod_rewrite is enabled. Can you have a look at the .htaccess file and correct it if anything is wrong there.